# Getting Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.auctiondbcluster.s6rzg.mongodb.net. When trying to connect to localhost when I am offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
MongoDB connected...
Development server live on http://localhost:3000
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.auctiondbcluster.s6rzg.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.auctiondbcluster.s6rzg.mongodb.net'
}
```

Everything works smooth when I am connected to my wifi but when I am offline and starting the server it gives this error. And by the way no I am not trying to connect to MongoDB online cluster, I am trying to connect to local host (mongodb://localhost:27017/auctionDB).

Here the function I am using in `app.js`

```
const runServer = async () =>{
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"){
    await connectDb(process.env.MONGODB_LOCAL_CONNECTION);
    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
      console.log(`Development server live on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    })
  } else {
    await connectDb(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING);
    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
      console.log(`Production server live on port ${PORT}`);
    })
  }
}

runServer();
```

In my `.env` file `NODE_ENV` is set to development.
Here is the `connectDb.js` function I am using to connect to the database

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/**
 * @description: Connect to the database by providing the connection string.
 * @param {String} uri | MongoDB URI
 * @default: mongodb://localhost:27017/auctionDB
 *
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
const connectDb = (url = process.env.MONGODB_LOCAL_CONNECTION) => {
    try {
      const con = mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      });
      if(con) console.log("MongoDB connected...")
    } catch(e){
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
};  

module.exports = connectDb;
```

[Here](https://github.com/Hritvik-Mohan/Auction-Project) is the entire project on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your MongoDB URL is [ mongodb://localhost:27017/ ], and not an online connection MongoDB URL.
At line [13](https://github.com/Hritvik-Mohan/Auction-Project/blob/main/configs/config.js#L13)

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should `await` the `mongoose.connect` call, not the whole function:

```
const connectDb = async (url = process.env.MONGODB_LOCAL_CONNECTION) => {
    try {
      const con = await mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      });
      if(con) console.log("MongoDB connected...")
    } catch(e){
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
};  

module.exports = connectDb;
```

```
const runServer = () =>{
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"){
    connectDb(process.env.MONGODB_LOCAL_CONNECTION);
    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
      console.log(`Development server live on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    })
  } else {
    connectDb(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING);
    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
      console.log(`Production server live on port ${PORT}`);
    })
  }
}

runServer();
```